# Can I find out who this belongs to 36R1pfifzXLu3FDaBVtTy42EX6qLmvpUcL

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent a payment to that address and it's not the business I thought it was. Can I find out where my Bitcoin went?

Answer (score 2):

In general no, The Bitcoin network does not keep track of what businesses or individuals own which addresses.

A few addresses are associated with some well-known businesses but nowadays people use a new receiving address for each transaction to improve privacy.

Criminals pretending to be genuine are likely to contact you offering to trace that address for an up-front fee. Take great care or you will lose even more money.